# Kubernetes Pods show 2/2 ready even though spec has only 1 replica

Tags: kubernetes

For some reason, a bunch of pods across multiple namespaces show multiple pods even though the spec for their deployment specifies `replicas: 1`.

Example:

```
  NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  calibre-9569796f5-d5gt8          1/1     Running   1          2d4h
> calibre-web-d4965df64-29t9c      2/2     Running   5          2d4h < this one right here for example
  jellyfin-67f58745dc-dbvss        1/1     Running   6          2d4h
```

Yet in my `deployment.yml` I have

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When listing pod the `Ready` column does not indicates replicas but `ready` containers inside the pod.

For example here I'm running pod with sidecar that open `kubectl proxy` for the 2nd one:

```
NAME                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kubectl-pod         2/2     Running            2          2d19h
```

You notice that it shows that both of my containers are ready.
In order to check replica counts you have list your deployments:

```
➜  ~ kubectl get deployments
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment   3/3     1            3           52d

➜  ~ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-9bf6f7ddf-858hh    1/1     Running            0          52d
nginx-deployment-9bf6f7ddf-rr65g    1/1     Running            0          52d
nginx-deployment-9bf6f7ddf-wsdpb    1/1     Running            0          52d
```